# Echo JSON values in the column

Tags: php, json, for-loop, foreach

JSON data in a single column. I want to print these JSON data, but only one of them is writing. What is the reason of this?

JSON: `{"bid":"123","bid":"1234","bid":"12345","bid":"123456"}`

```
| id|  bSQ  |                       bID                              |
|---|-------|--------------------------------------------------------|
| 1 |  2019 |{"bid":"123","bid":"1234","bid":"12345","bid":"123456"} |
| 2 |  2019 |                       ..                               |
| 3 |  2019 |                       ..                               |
```

PHP :

```
if ($dataFromDBqas) {
  foreach ($dataFromDBqas as $dataFromDB) {
    $libBookHuge = $dataFromDB->bID;
    $hugeArray = json_decode($libBookHuge, true); 
        foreach ($hugeArray as $key => $value) {
              echo "Book ID: ".$value ."<br>";
           } 
   }
}
```

Result:

> Book ID: 123456

Why only one row of data?

Comment: The problem is that your JSON contains duplicate keys. The keys must be unique.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/Eus9j

Comment: @UgoT. If I remove `bid`, then can I print all ID numbers with PHP code?

Comment: Yes but in a json array, like that for instance : `[123, 1234, 12345]`, see http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d3cbd04ba36a215b629f4faedd2e98971f4772a4

Comment: @UgoT. Yes! This is so good! If you send post, I can accept your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that the JSON contains duplicate keys (`bid`) :

`{"bid":"123","bid":"1234","bid":"12345","bid":"123456"}`

To make it works, you can create some unique keys in your JSON object or simply create a JSON array :

`["123", "1234", "12345", "123456"]`

Here is [a working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d3cbd04ba36a215b629f4faedd2e98971f4772a4).